# Using selection.find to query database

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro and am not familiar with the intricacies of the selection.find query.

Background: I'm trying to check whether a member (sheet 1) holds a first aid qualification (data of which is in sheet 2). I want the macro to find the qualification using their member number from sheet 1 and output text in a new cell in sheet 1 "held" if the qualification appears on the list in sheet 2, and "not held" if the qualification doesn't appear on the list. I keep getting stuck where the code doesn't find the first aid qualification and stops (which ironically is exactly what I'm trying to do but instead I want it to output the previously mentioned text into a cell if the qualification can't be found).

Input sample is quite simple: basically two arrays of data (header fields in sheet 1: Member number, name, First Aid current. Header fields in sheet 2: Member number, name, qualifications (multiple which may or may not include first aid, this is the field I am wanting to query)). I tried the syntax:

```
Selection.Find(What:="first aid", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

with the view to populate the cell in sheet 1 with held/not held based on the outcome of the search. Errors I have been getting are "Run-time error 450: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" and "Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Thanks for your reply David, sorry for omitting those details. I have updated the post.

Comment: If Find doesn't make a match then there is nothing to activate - you first need to check whether find returned a `Range` (cell) or `Nothing`

Comment: Did you try to make a query and record it with the Macro Recorder?

Comment: Yes, I started with the Macro Recorder. Usually I start this way and modify the code to clean it up/extend the range, loop etc. but I can't seem to figure this one out.